# Algebra quotient space homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove the following; Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $K$. If $I \subset A$ is an ideal, then there exists a unique algebra structure on the quotient vector space $A/I$ such that the canonical projection $\pi: A \rightarrow A/I$ is an algebra homomorphism.

Here is my "proof".

Denote the multiplication map on $A$ by $m:A\times A\rightarrow A$ with $(x,y)\rightarrow m(x,y)$ which is bilinear by definition of an algebra Let $x\in A$. Then $\pi$ maps $x$ to the equivalence class of $x$, denoted $[x]$, so 
$$\pi(x)=[x]$$.

Addition and scalar multiplication on $A/I$ is defined by $[x]+[y]=[x+y]$ and $[ax]=a[x]$ $\forall a\in K$.

It then follows immediately that $\pi$ is a $K$-linear map. It remains to show that there is a unique algebra structure on $A/I$ such that $\pi$ is compatible with algebra multiplication. Endow $A/I$ with a multiplication operation $$m_I:A/I\times A/I\rightarrow A/I, \quad ([x],[y])\rightarrow m_I([x],[y])$$.

For $\pi$ to be compatible with multiplication it must satisfy 
$$\pi (m(x,y))=m_I(\pi(x),\pi(y))=m_I([x],[y])$$

This is satisfied if and only if we define multiplication on $A/I$ by 
$$m_I([x],[y])=[m(x,y)]$$
It is easy to verify that this bilinear and hence makes $A/I$ into an algebra, and since it's an "if and only if" argument it's the unique one that makes $\pi$ into a homomorphism.

However, nowhere have I used the fact that $I$ is an ideal. Where's the problem?

Edit: Update: I must show that the map $m_I$ is well-defined in both of its arguments. I do this for the first argument, the second is the same. I must show that if $[z]=[x]$ then $m_I([x],[y])=m_I([z],[y])$.

Let $[x]=[z]$. Then $z=x+n$, for some $n\in I$. Hence, $$m_I([z],[y])=[m(z,y)]=[m(x,y)+m(n,y)]=[m(x,y)]+[m(n,y)]$$

But $I$ is an ideal hence $m(n,y)\in I$ $\forall y\in I$. Hence $[m(n,y)]=I=[0_A]$. Hence 
$$m_I([z],[y])=[m(z,y)]=[m(x,y)]+[0_A]=[m(x,y)+0_A]=[m(x,y)]=m_I([x],[y])$$
as required.

Comment: If $\;I\;$ is not an ideal none of your operations is well defined...just like trying to "define" a product the usual way in a group modulo a non-normal subgroup.

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you. I have updated my question with this new information. Is this correct now?